# Covariates in a case control study

Tags: logistic, predictor, association-rules, case-control-study, exact-test

I am doing a retrospective analysis on a study has has cases and controls. I am looking to see if there is an association with death, using exact logistic regression. I am confused on whether I need to include covariates in the model that are associated with the outcome (death) or the independent variable of interest (say disease X or no disease X). I have done a univariate analysis by disease and have noted the significant variables, but I think the covariates are supposed to be variables significantly associated with the outcome, not the disease. Is this correct?